# Pandas - instead of dropping rows with nan values I want to keep those rows and drop the others in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I have several column in my df, one is `error`. If that column has rows with a value (this one always has 99 as the error message value) I want to remove those rows and keep the ones that are nan.

df:

| error | date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | nan | nan |
| nan | 2022-02-01 | 234 |
| nan | 2022-02-02 | 34643 |
| 99 | nan | nan |
| nan | 2022-03-02 | 23425 |
| 99 | nan | nan |

I know how to drop if nan, but I want to do the opposite for the error column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more general solution than proposed by *enke* is:

```
df = df[df.error.isna()]
```

This way you retain only rows with *NaN* in *error* column,
regardless of the error value in original DataFrame.